# eeptools age_calc() error: End date must be a date after date of birth

Tags: r, date, intervals

[image]

I'm using `age_calc()` from the `eeptools` package in R but am getting the error

> End date must be a date after date of birth

Both the dob and end date are date class objects with format `%yyyy-%mm-%dd`

```
x$age<- floor(age_calc(dob = x$Date.of.Birth2, enddate = x$DisbursalDate2,
                   units = "years", precise = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this question is old now, but just in case anybody else comes across this looking for an answer.

The coding behind the `age_calc()` function uses the following logic:

```
  if (any(enddate < dob)) {
    stop("End date must be a date after date of birth")
  }
```

So you are getting the error because at least one of your enddate values ('DisbursalDate2' in your case) is before the dob value ('Date.of.Birth2' in your case). To find out what is causing the error, just do:

```
subset(x, x$DisbursalDate2 < x$Date.of.Birth2)
```